# C# Windows Forms Application Read Textbox Line by Line

Tags: c#, textbox, richtextbox, windows-forms-designer

I want to make a program that has a multiline textbox, and the program will read it line by line.
All I need is to get the line into a string, and after I'm finished with that line, it moves on.
How can I do that?
Is there a built in function, like there is the `getline()` function in c++ and c?
Should I use a normal textbox or a richtextbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TextBoxBase.Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) property is what you're looking for.

Per request, here's a sample:

**Code:**

```
namespace SomeApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // For each line in the rich text box...
            for (int i = 0; i < richTextBox.Lines.Length; i++)
            {
                // Show a message box with its contents.
                MessageBox.Show(richTextBox.Lines[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp# is more accurate. Thanks!

Comment: @user3882772 It's the same link.  Mark as an answer if it helped.

Comment: nice answer, you may perhaps add some sample code too.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit confused. I'll give you best answer if you explain each line.

Comment: @pushpraj No problem.  Added a sample.

Comment: @user3882772 Check my edit.  I included a sample program for you.